# How to create Custom Transformer in Apache Camel

Tags: json, spring-boot, apache-camel

`I have to transform  json to json by using apache camel, for which I want to create a custom transformer in apache camel. But not able to do it.

I have tried with by extending Transformer class of Apache Camel. But not able to get what to do next inside its overridden tranform() method.`

Answer (score 0):

See some of the EIPs such as *message translator*: https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/message-translator.html